# Using PayPal REST API with Firebase Functions (XMLHttpRequests)

Tags: javascript, paypal, xmlhttprequest, google-cloud-functions, paypal-rest-sdk

I actually already solved this problem, but it took me a while to do it, so I decided that I might as well spend the time to write this up to help anyone else who might go through the same issue.

I started out trying to use the PayPal REST API with Firebase Functions via the XMLHttpRequest object. based on the [PayPal docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/get-an-access-token-curl/) this was my code (emulating a cURL command with the XMLHttpRequest object):

```
const XMLHttpRequest = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest;

// 1b. Point towards PayPal servers
const paypalOAuthAPI = 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/' +
    'v1/oauth2/token/';
const paypalAuthAPI = 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/' +
    'v2/payments/authorizations/';

// 1c. Get an access token from the PayPal API
const client = 'your-really-long-client-string-token';
const secret = 'your-really-long-client-secret-string-token';
const basicAuthString = client + ':' + secret;
const basicAuth = Base64.encode(basicAuthString);

const auth = new XMLHttpRequest();

auth.onload = () => {
    console.log('Recieved auth response:', auth);
    console.log('Recieved auth status:', auth.status);
    console.log('Recieved auth responseText:', auth.responseText);
};

auth.open('POST', paypalOAuthAPI, true);
auth.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
auth.setRequestHeader('Accept-Language', 'en_US');
auth.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + basicAuth);
return auth.send('grant_type=client_credentials');
```

This was the fix (I left out a couple of headers that cURL adds in):

```
auth.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
auth.setRequestHeader('Content-Length', '29');
```

And there you have it! I hope that this helps anyone with the same issue.

Comment: Thanks for sharing.  Usually, you write a question then answer it yourself.  ;)